# Dynamically setting height of the uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a tableview cell with name, image, comment, attachment and like dislike button. The attachment is optional. If there is any attachment, it should have a fixed height constraint, otherwise 0. The cell is created programmatically. The problem is, although the dynamic height with the comment size is taking place, the dynamic height for attachment not getting set and causing fluctuation. I'm attaching the codes below. Can anyone please help.

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    backgroundColor = .clear
    
    contentView.addSubview(backView)
    contentView.addSubview(descLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(userImage)
    contentView.addSubview(posterLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(likeBtn)
    contentView.addSubview(flagBtn)
    contentView.addSubview(likeLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(flagLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(commentImage)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        userImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
        userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 25),
        userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        
        posterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
        posterLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.centerYAnchor),
        posterLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        
        descLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
        descLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
        descLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 75),            descLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30),
        
        commentImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descLabel.leadingAnchor),
        commentImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        commentImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
        
        likeBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.leadingAnchor),
        likeBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        likeBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        likeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
        likeBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
        
        likeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeBtn.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        likeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
        
        flagBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
        flagBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        flagBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        flagBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeBtn.bottomAnchor),
        
        flagLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: flagBtn.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        flagLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: flagBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
        
        backView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
        backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
        backView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
        backView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
    ])
    
    commentImageHeightConstraint = commentImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    commentImageHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
    
    likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(voteComment(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    flagBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(flagComment(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: To make attachment optional, your should put attachment in stackView and then hide/show it as per need. So when you will hide attachment present in stackView, attachment will get 0 height, means it will disappear and vice versa.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and get back. Thanks for the way. out.

Comment: Hey thanks, forgot to inform, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Please make give my answer correct answer and close this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: done mate (y) (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make attachment optional, your should put attachment in **stackView** and then **hide/show** it as per need. **So when you will hide attachment present in stackView, attachment will get 0 height**, means it will disappear and vice versa.
Eg:

```
    button.isHidden = true
//Now this button will be optional, means it will have 0 height, width.
```

If you want to show button.

```
    button.isHidden = true
//Button will be shown like miracle.
```